# Django createview creates extra instance without foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am using Django createview to create Bid items in an auction site. The createview will create the new object but it creates an extra object instance without the corresponding foreign keys. I am using @staticmethod to to ascertain whether the bid being submitted is indeed the highest bid then create in related Listing. Thank you in advance if you could point what im doing incorrectly.

models.py

```
class Bid(TimeStampMixin):
    """model representing bid obj"""
    auction = models.ForeignKey(
        Listing, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        related_name='offer', 
        null=True)
    bidder = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null=True,
        related_name='bid_user')
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    objects = BidQuerySet.as_manager()

        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.amount} in Listing No: {self.auction.id}"

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['amount']

    @staticmethod
    def high_bid(auction, bidder, bid_amount):
        """util method to ascertain highest bid in auction then create in related auction obj
        :param auction---listing being bid on, bid__auction
        :param bidder---user bidding
        :param amount--- current highest bid
        """
        ###error checks, is auction running? is current bid less than start bid? etc
        if bid_amount < auction.start_bid:
            return
        if (auction.highest_offer and bid_amount < auction.highest_offer.amount):
            return
        if bidder.id is auction.user.id:
            raise PermissionDenied
        ##after checks create highest bid object in listing model
        new_high_bid = Bid.objects.create(
            auction= auction,
            bidder = bidder,
            amount = bid_amount
        )
        auction.highest_offer = new_high_bid
        auction.save()

class Listing(TimeStampMixin):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="seller")
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="item")
    start_bid = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0)
    date_end = models.DateTimeField()
    duration = models.ForeignKey(
        Duration, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    ###static method in Bid model creates this
    highest_offer = models.ForeignKey(
        'Bid',
        related_name = 'highest_bid',
        on_delete = models.SET_NULL,
        null = True,
        blank = True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Listing for {self.product} by {self.user}."
```

views.py

```
class BidCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    """View to create auction bid"""
    model = Bid
    form_class = BidForm
    template_name = "auction/auction_detail.html"

    ##define url redirected to when form is valid 
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse ('detail', kwargs = { 'pk' : self.auction.pk })

    ###get context data to be passed to view
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        bidder = self.request.user
        ###call parent class to init 
        c = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        c["auction"] = self.auction
        ###check if user is bidding on own item
        if bidder.id is self.auction.user.id:
            c["form"] = None
        return c

    ###get_form_kwargs() method to supply user and listing during form creation
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        ###call parent class
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        ###extrack PK from kwargs so we can query for related listing obj
        pk_ = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        auction = Listing.objects.get(pk = pk_)
        kwargs["auction"] = auction
        self.auction = auction
        print(kwargs)
        return kwargs

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return super().form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        bid_amount = form.cleaned_data["amount"]

        try:
        ###use transaction.atomic to tie this method with a succesful form submission
            with transaction.atomic():
                Bid.high_bid(
                    self.auction,
                    self.request.user,
                    bid_amount
                )
        except IntegrityError:
            messages.error(self.request, "An unexpected error has occured")

        messages.success(self.request, "Bid submitted successfully!")

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

forms.py

```
class BidForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = [
            'amount',
        ]

        widgets = {
            'amount' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """override __init__ pop related auction from kwargs"""   
        self.auction = kwargs.pop("auction", None)
        ##call super with related obj 
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        

    ##clean data/validate, ensuring bid is larger than highest bid and starting bid
    def clean_amount(self):
        amount = self.cleaned_data["amount"]
        ##check if less than starting bid
        if self.auction.start_bid > amount:
            raise ValidationError(_('Bid is less than starting bid'))
        if (self.auction.highest_offer.amount >= amount):
            raise ValidationError(_('Bid is less than current highest bid'))
        return amount
```

DB table showing extra bid object without foreign keys

[DB table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SWfv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `return super().form_valid(form)` line from form_valid.

This line of code will call form_valid from the inherited class which will save the object - this is the extra object being created with no foreign keys.

Instead you will want to return some sort of http response (e.g render_to_response, redirect etc.).

Comment: worked like a charm thank you. just to be clear  super().form_valid(form) would call form_valid twice, creating the extra object? Sorry im new to oop in python and am trying to get a better understanding

Comment: I can try to explain: Your view is inheriting from CreateView, there is a form_valid function in CreateView that will run `form.save()`, this will create an object based on the values in the form - this is the default behaviour of a CreateView. You ended up with two objects being created because you call Bid.high_bid in your form_valid (which ultimately creates a Bid object) and then you invoke the default CreateView behaviour by calling `super.form_valid(form)` which creates another Bid object.